# testing c++ iterator

Tags: c++, unit-testing, iterator, standards-compliance

I'm writing a c++ `RandomAccessIterator` for a custom array type.
Since it doesn't work with `std::sort` and a simple `int` array, I'd like to make sure that I have implemented it correctly.

> Do you know of any "iterator conformance testing" framework out there?

I have implemented every possible function or `operator`, and everything seems correct, but I still  miss something since `sort()` dereferences `array::end()`

Comment: I don't understand what you're saying about `sort`. It certainly does not dereference the *end*-iterator, and there's no reason why a custom iterator should not work with it.

Comment: @jalf: This could happen if the instance the comparison operator of the custom iterator does not work correctly if one of the iterators is `end`.

Comment: Why don't you post the relevant sections of your custom array type?

Comment: @Space_C0wb0y : could you give an hint of what should be the semantic of that operator? I could not find anything on how it should behave in detail, in particular regarding to the end() iterator value (thank you)

Comment: @Space_C0wb0y: that's true. But really, saying "incorrect code can behave incorrectly" should hardly come as a surprise to anyone. ;)

Comment: @QbProg: it should compare the iterators, without dereferencing iterators that cannot be dereferenced. In general, it seems strange for iterator comparison to dereference the iterators *at all*, but there's no rule against it -- as long as you only dereference dereference-able ones.

Comment: Two iterators should be equal *if they reference the same object*. The equality of the pointed-to object is irrelevant. An iterator pointing to an int with the value `4` is not equal to an iterator pointing to *another* int which also has the value `4`. So I can't really see why dereferencing in `operator==` or `operator<` should be necessary at all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [`Boost.Iterator`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/iterator/doc/index.html)-library contains classes for concept checking.